# Fid sample size based on num of rows in data

Tags: r, split, lapply

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| Region | Name |
| --- | --- |
| Region 1 | Name 14 |
| Region 2 | Name 18 |
| Region 2 | Name 2 |
| Region 2 | Name 21 |
| Region 2 | Name 44 |
| Region 3 | Name 64 |
| Region 3 | Name 24 |
| Region 4 | Name 1 |
| Region 4 | Name 1 |
| Region 4 | Name 98 |
| Region 5 | Name 98 |
| Region 5 | Name 8 |
| Region 5 | Name 8 |
| Region 5 | Name 8 |
| Region 5 | Name 98 |

I need to breakup the data by Region, and then select a random sample of only 5% of the "Name" per Region, based on the number of rows in Region.

So lets say there are 30 Name in Region 2, then i need a random sample of 3*.05. If there are 50 Name in Region 6, then i need a random sample of 5*.05.

So far, ive been able to split() the data using

`d = split(data, f = data$Region)`

but when i try to run an lapply function i get an error that there are different number of rows in the list that split() provided

```
lapply(data, function(x) {
 sample_n(data, nrow(d)*.05)
} )
```

Any thoughts?

Thank you

Comment: share the rest of your code and error message, don't supply pictures of your data use `dput()` to share your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a base R solution.

```
lapply(split(data, data$Region),
       \(x) x[sample(nrow(x), nrow(x) * 0.05),])
```

You can then convert it back into a data frame with `rbind`

Comment: thanks, is there a typo with the "\"?  im getting the error "Error: unexpected input in:
"lapply(split(data, data$Region),
       \"
"

Comment: @DeebaYavrom Perhaps you're using an old version of R. Try replacing `\(x)` with `function(x)`